# Retornar valor de um método PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para retornar uma variável para fora do objeto executando um método em PHP.

Segue o código:

**connection.php**

```
<?php
class Connection {
    protected $db_host;
    protected $db_user;
    protected $db_pass;
    protected $database;

    function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database){
        $this -> db_host = $db_host;
        $this -> db_user = $db_user;
        $this -> db_pass = $db_pass;
        $this -> database = $database;
    }

    function getDB_host(){
        return $this -> db_host;
    }

    function getDB_user(){
        return $this -> db_user;
    }

    function getDB_pass(){
        return $this -> db_pass;
    }

    function getDatabase(){
        return $this -> database;
    }

    function setDB_host($db_host){
        $this -> db_host = $db_host;
    }

    function setDB_user($db_user){
        $this -> db_user = $db_user;
    }

    function setDB_pass($db_pass){
        $this -> db_pass = $db_pass;
    }

    function setDatabase($database){
        $this -> database = $database;
    }

    function connect(){
        @$connection = mysqli_connect($this -> getDB_host(), $this -> getDB_user(), $this -> getDB_pass(), $this -> getDatabase());
        if(mysqli_connect_errno($connection)){
            echo "Erro ao fazer conexão com MySQL";
            die();
        }
        // eu quero fazer o retorno da variáel '$connection' para fora do objeto
    }

}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $newConnection = new Connection('127.0.0.1' /* 'Servidor do MySQL' */, 'root' /* 'Usuário do MySQL */, '*****' /* 'Senha do MySQL*/, 'database' /* 'Database do MySQL' */);
    $newConnection -> connect();
    // eu quero extrair aqui o valor da variável '$connection' do método connect()
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode retornar o valor da conexão e fazer consultas a partir dela.
vou te dar um exemplo no código abaixo.

```
<?php

class Database {
  private $hostname;
  private $username;
  private $password;
  private $basename;

  public function __construct(String $hostname, String $username, String $password, String $basename) {
    $this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->basename = $basename;
  }

  public function connection() {
    return mysqli_connect(
      $this->hostname,
      $this->username,
      $this->password,
      $this->basename
    );
  }
}

$database = new Database("localhost", "root", "ascent", "db");
$connection = $database->connection();

var_dump($connection);
```

No código acima eu crio uma classe com nome Conexão onde ela é responsável por receber os valores da conexão no seu constructor e os valores são privados a classe, e você deixa o método de conexão público para usar fora da classe, veja mais no link: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Obrigado, ajudo muito.